# How I can make Markov chain model by training data?

Tags: machine-learning

I have to produce Markov chain model by training given data.  Data is available at website http://www.ll.mit.edu/ideval/data/ . I am trying to make Markov chain model given in IEEE paper **Nong Ye, Senior Member, IEEE, Yebin Zhang, and Connie M. Borror '*Robustness of the Markov-Chain Model for Cyber-Attack Detection'*pp. 116-123** . Markov Chain model considers  1-step transition probabilities. Markov chain model depends on Transition probability matrix. So how I can form Markov Chain model?

Comment: Do u have a state diagram??

Comment: No, i don't have state diagram readily available. I have to obtain this from given data.

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is it a long chain of states?

Comment: It would be better if you define your problem clearly rather than giving external reference.

Comment: @Neeraj I've tried to give some general suggestions, we don't have data and we don't know much about cyber security.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your situation, because I found myself similar when I got started. I can share you my own experience:

**Forming a markov model relies on strong knowledge of the data**

It's absolutely hopeless randomly apply Markov models to the data. There's no rule how many states you need to have, it depends on your data and problem. Your first step is to verify the data even satisfy the Markov property, can you assume the next state only assumes the current state? You can usually tell with experience and knowledge in our field. I don't know anything about cyber attack, so I can't comment on the data. You will need to do some homework, look at the data, do they look like a sequence of states? Do they look like a sequence of non-random patterns? Read what everybody has done, make sure you are happy that you can apply a markov model on it. Learn about your data, don't just apply something because somebody has done it for a paper. The data for the paper might be different.

**Estimation**

The number of states can often be estimated. Once again, this requires strong domain knowledge. In bioinformatics (my domain knowledge), the number of states is often related to biology. For example, there are four base pairs in DNA, so I would start off with a model with those four states.

**Optimization**

You'll need to create many models and fit with the best one. Statistics like AIC, BIC etc can help you.

[This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-scientists-come-up-with-the-correct-hidden-markov-model-to-use) is a similar question. You see, it requires your skills and understanding of the problem.